Movie about two sisters trying to rob a mafia boss
I remember watching that movie not so long ago but I can't put a title on it.
In that movie, we see 2 sisters from Eastern Europe taking the bus to Germany. There one of the sister became an escort while her sister disapproves. During one of her gigs with a mafia mob, she called her boss so they can rob the guy. During that time, the mafia mob's bodyguard waits in the car where he met the second sister. At the end of the movie, the bodyguard and the sister are living together to change life. The mafia mob and the boss are dead.
That movie was released during the last decade. I think it was in English.
The bodyguard was living in Paris with his girlfriend. She was pissed off because of their relationship. Then the bodyguard left her to pick his boss at the airport.

Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. Feel free to edit your question and add these details. Also see How to Ask Identify-this-X questions. Thank you.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title. It's clear you're looking for the title of a movie and neither are you the first person to ever do so.

@NapoleonWilson You're right but I don't know what relevant information I can add to the title. If you have ideas, that would be great!

You couldn't find anything from your whole question that might make the title better than "help find movie"? I gave it a try.
